# Which champion performs better in the early season 7 meta?

Tags: league-of-legends

Currently, I'm saving up IP for some champions so I can finally played ranked with characters that I can play efficiently. For top, I'm deciding whether to use Gnar or Jayce. For jungling, I'm deciding whether to use Graves or Lee Sin.

So which of those champions performs better in this tank meta?

All of the characters I have stated I have experience or past experience with.

Comment: http://champion.gg/statistics/#?roleSort=Jungle&sortBy=general.winPercent&order=descend

Comment: I voted to re-open because it seems to fit with this meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/11340/101016, mainly the "Who is stronger, x or y?" section.

Comment: @camelCase It says "This should be allowed, **but only as long as the question itself specifies the scenario.**" The scenario needs to be something specific that guarantees a definitive answer, rather than an opinion. The OP did not do that, so the question should remain closed as highly opinion-based.

Comment: Guys, don't forget to supports. Sona is still so broken, and she can carry game as a support with strong Q!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 6.24, due to new changes high HP Champions with hard Crowd Control are stronger, due to **Strenght of the Colossus**. It provides a shield based on your **max HP** multiplied by the number of **nearby enemy champions**.

That means *Nautilus, Sion, Darius & Hecarim*. [High Elo Winrates](http://champion.gg/) confirm this. Since you're mostly referring to toplane I intentionally left out other champions who are only strong because of how the jungle changes (or their kits) work only on the jungle (such as Shyvana and Amumu who are also on good spots)

Evidently their counters are also in a good(ish) spot, and champions such as Vayne who was already strong will be a threat to you

Answer (score 1):

Play the champs you're most comfortable with.  Gnar and Jayce are great.  Jayce can also be played extremely effectively mid lane.  As a top mainer, that only plays bruisers, I consistently hate to see Gnar and Jace match ups.  Seems this meta doesn't exactly require tanks, if laning phase can go favorably enough.